# Comparison of JBoss AS 7.x and Glassfish 3.x?

Tags: glassfish-3, jboss7.x

I was wondering if there is a (mostly) objective comparison between the `JBoss AS 7` and `Glassfish 3.x`?

I don't care for any differences in standards or their implementation, I was thinking more about *startup time, failover, scalability, performance, memory footprint, known problems, administration, security, clustering* etc.

**Real world examples & experiences are very welcome!**

Answer (score 6):

My opinion is that after the aquisition of Red Hat to JBoss the general quality of documentation has dropped significantly. Even if JBoss is the better product in my next project I will shift to GlassFish because of the better documentation. Who cares about the startup plan if you loose 2/3 of your time dealing with lack of proper documentation?
JBoss 4 and 5 wer an examples of a properly documented products. Things have changes for worse.

Comment: I think they want to sell the documentation. I saw many free software where the strategy is "ok, it is free, but if you need documentation you have to pay for it".

Answer (score 5):

Antonio Goncalves recently did a comparison of all the latest application servers including some of the metrics you requested - http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/o-java-ee-6-application-servers-where-art-thou/ .

Comment: interesting, but limited: it only compares start up times of the empty container, and memory footprint at start up.

Answer (score 5):

I found this introduction to JBoss AS7 with short memory/startup comparison to Glassfish 3.1.1: http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/10/jboss-as-7-catching-up-with-java-ee-6.html

Answer (score 1):

Real-world experiences for GlassFish are here: http://blogs.oracle.com/stories

Comment: Are they really "real-world" and objective? :)

Comment: marked down: stories on the product owners website can't be considered a reliable source for comparison

Comment: @dstibbe I think you may not have read the stories, they're all provided by users.

Comment: @Nightsorrow they're absolutely real-world. As for objectivity, I'll let you decide if they're relevant for your particular use-case. This is a way for users to share with the rest of the community their experience. Good and not so good. It helps improve the product too. Feel free to ignore if there isn't value for you.